# do amd64 platform images run the same on mac silicon?

Tags: docker

As we know already, there are several platforms available to run on docker.
On Mac OS though, docker is based on a hypervisor called Hyperkit, so I guess we use a virtual machine.
I was wondering if there are any difference between `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64/v8`one when running on a mac silicon.

Plus: what if we generate a `linux/amd64` image on a mac m1? is the amd64 environment emulated by qemu? so: would there be qemu on top of the hypervisor? just the hypervisor?

Comment: Docker Desktop is not a VM and does not use a hypervisor.  It uses qemu to run amd64 images on an arm64 Mac.  arm64 images run natively.

Comment: and what about namespaces and cgroups? I knew mac didn't support them. actually, this article stated something different: https://collabnix.com/how-docker-for-mac-works-under-the-hood/

Answer (score 0):

It don't run the same since it is not the same platform, docker need to utilize emulation/Virtualization.

You should make it a default to run arm64 images on apple silicon but, if it's neccesary/mandatory you can run amd64 with docker desktop for m1
just use flag:

```
 docker run --platform linux/amd64
```

[docker run doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

About your other question Docker removed the requirment for Rosetta 2 for the installation process but, they still state that it is needed for some CLI tools such as "using Darwin/AMD64", based on that i think it is safe to assume that the emulation/virtualization "tool" is Rosetta 2 :)

[Apple silicon (M1) System requirements](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/#system-requirements)